# Does AWS Lex support emoji conversations & intent ?

Tags: amazon-lex

I've tried building an intent that targets :thumbsup: and also the unicode representation U+1F44D

how can I build an intent around emojis ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately `:thumbsup:` and `U+1F44D` will be invalid.

> An utterance can consist only of Unicode characters, spaces, and valid
>   punctuation marks. Valid punctuation marks are: periods for
>   abbreviations, underscores, apostrophes, and hyphens.

You have to handle emoji before sending it to Lex. Like if you get `:thumbsup:` value then send `thumbsup` to Lex and it will handle that intent.